# How to Switch Between Front and Primary Camera on Button Click Event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, camera

I am using the PhotoCamera class to populate a VideoBrush and take pictures in an application. By default I set the camera to front facing. However, I would like to be able to switch between the primary and front facing camera when both exist. I set up a button for this, but I'm not sure how to properly implement this. What I have so far is as follows

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        //Set up the Camera
        if (null == camera)
        {
            InitializeCamera();
        }
    }

private void InitializeCamera()
    {
        // Check to see if the camera is available on the device.
        if ((PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true) || (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing) == true))
        {
            // Initialize the camera, when available.
            if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing))
            {
                // Use front-facing camera if available.
                camera = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, use standard camera on back of device.
                camera = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
            }

            camera.Initialized += camera_Initialized;

            //Event is fired when the button is half pressed
            CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed += camera_ButtonHalfPress;

            //Event is fired when the button is fully pressed
            CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += camera_ButtonFullPress;

            //Event is fired when the capture sequence is complete and an image is available.
            camera.CaptureImageAvailable += camera_CaptureImageAvailable;

            camera.CaptureCompleted += camera_CaptureCompleted;

            //Set the VideoBrush source to the camera
            videoBrush.SetSource(camera);
        }
    }

private void UninitializeCamera()
    {
        camera.Dispose();

        CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed -= camera_ButtonFullPress;
        CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed -= camera_ButtonHalfPress;
        camera.CaptureImageAvailable -= camera_CaptureImageAvailable;

        camera = null;
    }

void sensor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != camera)
            {
                //Determine what cameras exist, and switch if able to
            }
    }
```

My main question is what is the best method to go about accomplishing this task considering my existing setup? Is there a better option?

Comment: may be with re initializing the camera on button click

Comment: Or, if you need to switch quickly, you could set up two VideoBrush components and always hide one of them. Not sure if this speeds it up, but probably worth a try.